# Transform img from url to file in React

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I have an autocomplete section that searches movies through MovieDB api.
The result of the api has a field called poster_path that contains the path where the image exists.

```
"poster_path": "/lRQiJXETkCnVVurHmglNvMXrZOx.jpg"
```

I have a react project for front-end and a spring boot project for backend.

The thing I want to do is to get the image convert it to file and the send it to the backend controller as a multipart file.

How can I convert the image from url to file in React?

I've tried this but re.data returns the byte array I think:

```
axios.get(e.image).then(re => {
      setFile(re.data)
    });
```

And here is the controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<Post> post(@RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file, @RequestPart @Valid PostResource postResource, Principal principal)
```

Comment: First convert image to DataURI (base64) and then convert it to a Blob file. You can then send it to your backend through FormData.

Comment: @TheoMartinez can you tell me how to convert it to DataURI and then to Blob? is there a package, or i can do it myself in react?